# What is the probability of that "More than half of the driest 10% of years in the historical record have occurred in the past two decades"

Tags: probability

There are 120 years of record so my first thought was that this is just a binomial probability problem.

There will be 12 years that represent the driest 10%, half would be 6 so we need the probability of getting 7 or more successes from 20 trials with a probability of success of 0.1.

In R

1 - pbinom(6, 20, 0.1) = 0.002386089

The problem is that this implies we could get more than 12 'driest 10% of years' in the past two decades, which is physically impossible from a 120 year record.

My next thought was to simulate.

1. Arrange the numbers 1:120 in random order
2. Count how many numbers in the range 1:12 (representing the driest 10% of years) occur in the final 20 elements of that random series)
3. Do this lots of times and count the number of occasions when this is 7 or more.

In R

```
Num_in_last_20 = function(){
  Ranks = sample(1:120, 120, replace = FALSE) # sort the numbers 1 to 120 in random order
  Last20 = Ranks[(length(Ranks) - 19): length(Ranks)] # Get the last 20 elements
  sum(Last20 %in% 1:12)  # in the lowest 10%
}


# Repeat lots of times to determine the
# probability there are 7 or more ranks less than 12 
mean(replicate(10000, Num_in_last_20() >= 7))
```

Approximately 0.0006179

I'd welcome help on the correct way to solve this problem.

Comment: This is a nice question to show that probabilities are model-bound. What's the probability that the hottest years occur recently is pretty high given that global warming has given us a rising baseline. You want to know what is the probability _assuming a constant baseline_, and that's what a binomial model will have.

Comment: @adriankahk I am not sure your second comment is correct: I would have thought if temperatures were i.i.d. from a continuous distribution, the probability that $X_{n+1}$ is higher than all of $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ is $\frac{1}{n+1}$ and this would be independent of  which of the earlier temperatures was the previous highest

Comment: That's a good point, cheers for the correction.

Comment: Weather trends tend to be correlated, sometimes strongly so, over periods spanning several to many years.  To obtain an honest, realistic answer to this question, then, *you cannot ignore this temporal correlation.* This makes it more complicated than a simple binomial or hypergeometric problem. The answer depends on the details, but what we do know is that the answer is going to be greater--perhaps far greater--than a calculation that assumes each year's weather is independent of the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming years are **independent**, it is [hypergeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) with $N=120, n=20, K = 12$. Let $X$ be the number of driest years in the last $20$ years. Then,
$$P(X=x)=\frac{{12\choose x}{108\choose 20-x}}{120\choose20}$$

And, the probability you want is $\sum_{x=7}^{12} P(X=x)\approx 0.000603$

Comment: It is *crucial* to explain that this answer makes a strong assumption--namely, that the annual results are independent--because it is well known that this assumption is false.

Comment: @whuber It' absolutely correct, and not realistic! This answer, as per assumed implicitly in the coding experiment performed by the author, assumes independence among years. And, as you've mentioned it in the above comment under the question, the answer for the realistic case needs greater details/clarifications on the structure and it'll highly likely need more analysis.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm happy with the independence assumption for this calculation because this analysis is part of a larger story about the fact that the data are not, in fact, independent.